# Android studio AVD manager throwing nothing selected

Tags: android-studio, centos7, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

I am trying to configure `AVD` on `android studio` on `Centos 7`.

I am able to successfully create a project. When trying to create `AVD`, I am choosing device definition as `Nexus 6 size: 5'.96",resolution 1440*2560, 560dpi`. Then, in the next setup screen, I choose system image screen which I have downloaded, as `MarshMallow, API Level:23, x86`. In next setup screen, (verify configuration) when I click the Finish button it showed `nothing selected`.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Had the exact same problem, try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: Centos doesn't use apt-get, try it with yum

Comment: what about in Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

In general: web search for your Linux version and how to add 32-bit libraries. Redhat (and Fedora and Centos), for instance, use a .i686 extension. Doing

```
sudo yum list lib\*.i686
```

outputs a whole bunch of libraries; look for libstdc++.

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
```

That will ask you whether to install dependencies. Answer 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the exact same problem, so I'm just updating all my plugins and repository and SDK. So I got the preview which I've selected in AVD Manager.

Hope it will work same in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this steps In: Verify Configuration page appears.

Change AVD properties as needed, and then click Finish.

Click Show Advanced Settings to show more settings, such as the skin.
The new AVD appears in the Your Virtual Devices page or the Select Deployment Target dialog.

To create an AVD starting with a copy:

From the Your Virtual Devices page of the AVD Manager, right-click an AVD and select Duplicate.
Or click Menu   and select Duplicate.

The Verify Configuration page appears.

Click Change or Previous if you need to make changes on the System Image and Select Hardware pages.

Make your changes, and then click Finish.

full description available in below link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer to you problem but instead of using Android AVD you can try GenyMotion which has better performance than AVD. It's free if you are using it non-commercially.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought it'd be helpful for anyone who has the same question and stumbles upon this. I resolved this by noticing that while the software version was selected, right above it, the hardware was not! I clicked "Change" (one of the two buttons that worked) and selected Pixel 2 (which just happened to be the default), and it worked.